# Browser side Dust.js

Tags: javascript, browser, dust.js

I've been trying to put together a really simple example using Dust.js in the Browser. Although the docs are very good there doesn't seem to be much information on getting things configured in the for browser.

So based on the following JSON data taken from the Linked-In Dust tutorial:

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-Show_me_some_Dust

```
{
   "title": "Famous People", 
   "names" : [{ "name": "Larry" },{ "name": "Curly" },{ "name": "Moe" }]
}
```

And this template:

```
 {title}
 <ul>
 {#names}
 <li>{name}</li>{~n}
 {/names}
  </ul>
```

How can this be sent up for rendering client side in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit down on the page you will find a basic example how to compile a template:
[Compiling a Dust Template](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#compiling-a-dust-template)

Basically you just have to call the `compile` function to register the template.

```
var compiled = dust.compile("Hello {name}!", "intro");
```

To use it immediately, execute `loadSource` to write the compiled template into dust's template library:

```
dust.loadSource(compiled);
```

Then you're able to `render` the template with your JSON-data:

```
dust.render("intro", {name: "Fred"}, function(err, out) {
    console.log(out);

    // or maybe with jquery:
    $('#container').html(out);
});
```

Comment: Perfect! - Got it thanks for you help! 

The only bit I also needed to add was this "dust.loadSource(compiled);"

Comment: Actually one quick question if my template contains characters that should be escaped. Does does have a function to do this?

e.g <li><a href="#"> <img src="./images/cn.jpg"> <h1 class="myHeader"><img src="./flags/cn.gif"> Key Device Name : {name} </h1><p class="myParagraph">Some meta data here</p></a></li>

Comment: Sorted - Just needed to add the escapes to the template!

Comment: Ok, thought the `loadSource` wouldn't be necessary :)
I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a browser example of DustJS too since the tutorials don't really mention it.

Here's a repo I created with an example:
https://github.com/ericktai/dust-js-browser

I use [duster.js](https://github.com/dmix/dusterjs) to compile the template.  The repo's README.md should describe the basics.

Hope it helps!

Erick